# Action Cable: broadcast different template content depending on the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb, actioncable

I have a delete link in a partial for a message that gets rendered in a chat by ActionCable. I'm checking with the following code if the `current_user` is admin or not and whether the user can see the link or not:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= link_to '[x]', msg, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "del-link" %>
<% end %>
```

But there happens to be an issue with this.
When a user, who is not `admin` submits a message, it gets rendered as 'not admin' for every user in the chat and the admin can see the link only after a refresh.
Vice versa it's the same, if an admin submits a message everyone can see the link.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are rendering a single template and broadcasting that to everyone, this behavior is to be expected. The basic problem is that when rendering the template to broadcast, `current_user` is the user posting the message, *not* the user receiving the update through Action Cable.

You could solve the problem entirely on the client side by doing something like this:

```
<%= link_to '[x]', msg, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "del-link admin-only" %>
```

Then add this CSS rule:

```
body:not(.with-admin) .admin-only {
  display: none;
}
```

And set the `with-admin` class on `<body>` if the current user is an admin:

```
<body class="<%= "with-admin" if current_user.admin? %>">
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

This way the visibility of `admin-only` elements is controlled by whether or not the current page was originally loaded as an admin, and the template broadcasted by Action Cable can have the same content for everyone.

**Important:** Make sure to validate the admin-ness of `current_user` in the `destroy` action before a message is actually deleted!